# An efficient way to convert sql to json

Tags: python, sql, json

Hi I have a data base which has around 1000000 rows.As I wanted to use mongodb I wrote the following code to convert it to json but it takes a lot of time.Is there another way to get around with this problem.

```
import psycopg2
import json
con = psycopg2.connect(database)
cur = con.cursor()
sql="select * from mini; "
cur.execute(sql) 
rows=cur.fetchall()
json_string=[]
for sample in rows:
    #print(sample)
    dicti={"label1":sample[0],"label2":sample[1],"label3":sample[2]}
    #print(json.dumps(dicti))
    json_string.append(dicti)
f=open('xyz.txt','w')
print >>f,json_string
f.close()
```

Here label1,label2,label3 are column names of sql if it helps.

Comment: Did you try to see what part is long by first commenting everything after `rows=cur.fetchall()` (measure fetch part), then commenting only from `f=open('xyz.txt','w')` (fetch + treatement). Anyway, you consume a lot of memory ...

Comment: I think the time is mainly due to cur.fetchall() as the data is humungous

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a dictionary for each row and then you convert it to a string. Skip the converting and create the json manually. I tested few approaches with timeit module:

1. Using str.format:

```python
>>> '{{"label1": {0}, "label2": {1}, "label3": {2}}}'.format('1','2','3')
>>> timeit.timeit("""'{{"label1": {0}, "label2": {1}, "label3": {2}}}'.format('1','2','3')""")
1.3898658752441406
```

1. Adding strings together:

```python
>>> '{"label1": ' + '1' + ', "label2": ' + '2' + ', "label3": ' + '3' + '}'
>>> timeit.timeit("""'{"label1": ' + '1' + ', "label2": ' + '2' + ', "label3": ' + '3' + '}'""")
0.506464958190918
```

1. Creating a dictionary:

```python
>>> str({"label1": '1', "label2": '2', "label3": '3'})
>>> timeit.timeit(""" str({"label1": '1', "label2": '2', "label3": '3'}) """)
4.776309013366699
```

There can be other possibilities how to create the json.

Answer (score 1):

Its a lot simpler to use the [`DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor), which will return dictionaries from your database:

```
import psycopg2
import json

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
rows = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mini')
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in rows:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(json.dumps(row)))
```

To dump the entire dataset as one large json object, do this instead:

```
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
rows = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mini')
dataset = list(rows)
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(dataset, f)
```

Comment: But I want a list of dictionaries which I am not getting by this method

Answer (score 0):

If the fetch part is where the majority of time is spent, it could be because you need a lot of memory and system has to do many reallocation or even worse is swapping. You could try to use fetchmany instead of fetchall with a *reasonable* size, and (same) write to disk by chunks.

So you would have something like :

```
import psycopg2
import json
con = psycopg2.connect(database)
cur = con.cursor()
sql="select * from mini; "
cur.execute(sql)
size = 256 # find a 'good' size
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        rows=curs.fetchmany(size)
        if len(rows) == 0:
            break
        json_string=[]
        for sample in rows:
            #print(sample)
            dicti={"label1":sample[0],"label2":sample[1],"label3":sample[2]}
            #print(json.dumps(dicti))
            json_string.append(dicti)
        print >>f,json_string
```

Comment: Hmm it actually doubled the time

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
sql = "SELECT row_to_json(row) FROM (select * from mini) row;"
cur.execute(sql)
result = cur.fetchone()
result[0]
# -> [{'col1':'val1', 'col2':'val2', ...}]
```